# Vapor 3 Routing

Tags: swift, vapor

## Routing problem

I’m using the latest version of Vapor and trying to learn it.

I’m trying to create a route in a controller. I have registered the controller in the routes.swift file. I now need to correctly register the routes in the controller file.

I have  extended the class using RouteCollection and am writing a route for a post request. I intend to pass a JSON object and have a class which is extended from Content to make it easier to create the object from JSON data.

The post request then submits data to a FoundationDB database. I have it reading and writing when I hard code it but now need to use requests to send data.

This is what I have.

```
func boot(router: Router) throws {
        router.post(  ) { // need to send JSON data in the request to the createCountry function
            
        
    }

func createCountry( ) { // I need to put the JSON data into a class called Country which has three string fields; country_name, Timezone and default_location. This will then be written to the foundationDB
        
       
    }
```

How should the **router.post()** be formatted and how should the **createCountry( )** function stub be formatted? I have been typing in req: Request and various -> to no avail. I’m obviously doing something wrong at a fundamental level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understand but to register the route and then handle the request you should write something like this:

```
class CountryController: RouteCollection {
    // Register routes for country
    func boot(router: Router) throws {
        let group = router.grouped("api", "country")
        group.post(Country.self, at: "new", use: newCountryHandler)
    }
}

private extension CountryController {

    func newCountryHandler(_ request: Request, newCountry: Country) throws -> Future<HTTPResponseStatus> {

        // Handle your new Country object
    }

}
```

Comment: That looks better than I have being trying. What Future to create was stumping me, but the HTTPResponeStatus looks good. Thanks